# How to use mercurial built-in templates?

Tags: mercurial, hgserve

Mercurial comes with some templates bundled. They may be stored in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/templates/` or in `/usr/share/mercurial/templates`.

In this folder there are few files:

```
map-cmdline.bisect
map-cmdline.changelog
map-cmdline.compact
map-cmdline.default
map-cmdline.xml
```

They're styles to use in command line e.g. `hg log -l 10 --style changelog`.

Alse there are folders:

```
atom
coal
gitweb
monoblue
paper
raw
rss
spartan
```

Each of them contains files like:

```
bookmarkentry.tmpl
bookmarks.tmpl
changelogentry.tmpl
changelog.tmpl
error.tmpl
filelog.tmpl
header.tmpl
map
tagentry.tmpl
tags.tmpl
```

I'm guessing these are templates to use with `hg serve`. While trying run hgweb with `-t` option i get following error:

```
$ hg serve -t paper
listening at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (bound to *:8000)
127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2012 14:16:38] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [14/May/2012 14:16:38] Exception happened during processing request '/':
Traceback (most recent call last):
   [traceback here]
RuntimeError: No hgweb templates found in ['paper']
```

Does anyone know what are this folders/files and how to run `hg serve` with different templates?

ps.: I use Mercurial 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `--style` flag to specify a template style such as gitweb or paper.

```
hg serve --style paper
```

This will look in the shared templates folder and use the set of templates there.  The `-t` option expects a path pointing to a set of templates.